# Projecting @AggregateVersion in Axon

Tags: java, cqrs, axon

I'm using annotation `@AggregateVersion` in my aggregate to handle optimistic concurrency. In order to receive this version in request, anybody that makes a request needs first to get current version from my view projection. Is there some standard way to project this version field (since, I guess, this should not be included inside events DTO)?

So far, the only thing I can think of is just to count projected events in projection and increase version +1 each time I project one of events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jasper's `MetaData` suggestion would've gotten you there, but there's an easier solution to this problem.

Axon uses the notion of `ParameterResolvers` (sadly only very shortly described [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/parameter-resolvers), but in more depth [here](https://axoniq.io/blog-overview/parameter-resolvers-axon)) to resolve things like the command/event/query, `MetaData` or a `MetaDataValue`. You can however also have the framework resolve the sequence number which in for an Event Sourced Aggregate **is** the aggregate version. You can do this by adding an `@SequenceNumber` annotated `Long` parameter in an Event Handling function.

Hence, you can write an event handler like so:

```
@EventHandler
public void on(YourEvent event, @SequenceNumber Long aggregateVersion) {
    // Update the query model And the aggregate version
}
```

Having said that, this will obviously require you to handle **all** events from an aggregate in the event handling component to be able to update the version accordingly. Luckily, Axon will recognize if you handle parent classes of an event payload. Thus, if you define an event class hierarchy, ensuring all events from a given aggregate implement `interface MyAggregateEvent`. You can thus write an Event Handler like this to cover all remaining events just for aggregate version updates which you'd otherwise wouldn't be interested in:

```
@EventHandler
public void on(MyAggregateEvent event, @SequenceNumber Long aggregateVersion) {
    // Update the aggregate version only
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

P.S. I just noticed that the [Handling Events page](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/event-handling/handling-events) of the reference guide does state the `@SequenceNumber` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. So far I am handling all events from an aggregate - but I definitely need to handle this in a better way, since tomorrow somebody can change that behavior. I guess there is no axon default marker interface for domain events?

Comment: Also, it seems that I cannot do version update only in single method with `MyAggregateEvent`? If I have event `YourEvent implements MyAggregateEvent`, and I have two `@EventHandler`s - one for `YourEvent` and other for `MyAggregateEvent` - only the most specific one will be invoked once (`YourEvent `). That means I have to have version logic in all of the methods (instead only in handler handling `MyAggregateEvent`).

Comment: Sneak peak: As Axon looks for the most specific implementation of the event it is handling, you could event get by with an event handler which handles `Object` ;-)
What would be cleaner is to handle `EventMessage<Object>` as the first parameter in the `@EventHandler` annotated method though. Maybe you can even do `DomainEventMessage<Object>`, but I am not a 100% sure about that.
The problem with this is that you'll  also handle events from other aggregates who's sequence number you do not want to take into account. Hence my suggestion to have an interface in place for the Aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `MetaData` to the messages (commands and events).

https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/messaging-concepts/supported-parameters-for-annotated-handlers give some information about that.

It could be an option to add some information to the metadata to prevent optimistic concurrency problems.

You can send messages like:

```
MetaData metaData = MetaData.with("mykey", "myvalue");
metaData.put("lockVersion", currentVersion);
commandGateway.send(new GenericCommandMessage(doSomethingCommand, metaData));
```

In aggregate command handler you can do something like this:

```
@CommandHandler
public handle(DoSomethingCommand cmd, MetaData metaData, @MetaDataValue("mykey") String someValue) {
    // ... version check between aggregateVersion and lockVersion

    MetaData eventMetaData = MetaData.with("lockVersion", aggregateVersion);
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(new GenericEventMessage(new SomethingDoneEvent(), eventMetaData));
}
```

And the same kind of logic in the event handling:

```
@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(SomethingDoneEvent evt, MetaData metaData) {
    // ...
}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm new into Axon Framework and Event Sourcing so maybe this is not a good option and/or there are better ways to do this.*